# react native props types of object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a type for my class's props, but I'm not sure if I should define object prop properties or I should just define the object as object ? 
this is my class

```
class MyClass extends Component<MyProps> { ... }
```

and this is `myProps`

```
type MyProps = {
  title: string,
  author: {
    id: number,
    username: string,
    email: string
  }
}
```

is it correct to do it like that ? or I just should define `author` as object ?

the idea is that inside the class I'm using `author`'s properties and I never use the object `author` itself. so I'm kinda confused.
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your component to receive these `author` properties separately, you can do that, but i'd go with the other approach of defining `author` as a shape of the properties you want it to have.

It would look like this :

```
static propTypes = {
  author: PropTypes.shapeOf({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    username: PropTypes.string,
    email: PropTypes.string
  })
};
```